# CSS Styling <a> tag in an a SVG

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to figure out how to style an anchor tag within a SVG.
I think I've tried every variation but none seem to work as intended.

The fill works on the .logoContact a{}, so I know I'm referencing the element but the cursor property doesn't work and none of the a:hover state work.

I've tried putting the `<a>` within the `<g class="logoEmail">` but that doesn't work. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. - CES

```css
.logoContact a {
  fill: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 1s;
}

.logoContact a:hover {
  fill: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 1s;
}
```

```html
<g class="logoContact">
  <a href="xxxx">
    <g class="logoEmail">
      <path d="xxxxxx" />
      <path d="xxxxxx" />
      <path d="xxxxxx" />
    </g>
  </a>
</g>
```

Comment: This works fine. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dyRoRwK - You will need to *demonstrate this not working*. I suspect it's a path or HTML error.

Comment: Note that SVG uses fill and stroke rather than the HTML color property.

Comment: If you want the svg to be a clickable link then put the a href outside not inside; try that?

Answer (score 0):

SVG elements does not have a color CSS property. Use fill or stroke instead. Here I have an example with a `<rect>` that changes color.

The selector is (`.logoContact a`) will control the fill/stroke for all child elements that does not have a more specific selector. So, in this case this effects the child `<rect>`.

```css
.logoContact a {
  transition: 1s fill ease-in-out;
  fill: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.logoContact a:hover {
  transition: 1s fill ease-in-out;
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <g class="logoContact">
    <a href="#">
      <g class="logoEmail">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
      </g>
    </a>
  </g>
</svg>
```